# MySQL - Inserting NULL in TIME type implicitely

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have the following DDL (data definition language)

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `attr1` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `attr2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now I'm trying to insert data like that:

```html
INSERT INTO mytable ( attr2 )
VALUES ( 'beatifulstring' )
```

Now I would expect the system to insert NULL implicitely at attr1 but it inserts 00:00:00.
How can I fix that?

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement contains a syntax error: there is a superfluous comma after the definition of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Presumably that is because you have edited out some further clauses for the sake of brevity?  Could we see those, please?  Merely removing that comma and running the code as you have shown results in a `NULL` value in `attr1` for me.

Comment: Same for me, I get `NULL` testing your code

Comment: To reproduce your issue, I only found that if you're trying to insert an invalid value (ie. some string) into field `attr1` it fills the field with `00:00:00`

Comment: @EdwinKrause: That will depend on one's [SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: Thank you Edwin Krause!
I found the error, it was a wrong if (isset(...)) clause in my php.